# What is the right quantum number of copper?

Tags: electronic-configuration

Copper has $[Ar] 3d^{10} 4s^1$ electron configuration. And zinc has $[Ar] 3d^{10} 4s^2$ electron configuration.

My question is, what are the right quantum numbers of the last electron of copper? Is it $$a. n=3,l=2,m=+1,s=-1/2$$ or $$b. n=3,l=2,m=+2,s=-1/2$$

If I use (a), the electron configuration of copper is $[Ar] 3d^{9} 4s^2$ and which isn't stable. But if I use quantum numbers in (b), it is the same with the last electron of zinc.

Answer (score 3):

The correct quantum numbers for last electron of Copper ($\ce{Cu}$) would be $B. n=3,l=2,m=+2,s=-1/2$.

> if I use B quantum numbers, it is the same with the last electron of zinc.

Yes, last electrons of Both can have same quantum numbers because Pauli Exclusion law says that no two electrons **in an atom can have all four quantum numbers same** but it doesn't say that two electrons of different atoms can't have all four quantum number same.

Refer [this](http://www.kentchemistry.com/links/AtomicStructure/quantumnumbers.htm) for more.